# CSS to resize based on the target's dimensions rather than the container's dimensions?

Tags: css

I have a number of images that are in the same scale but have varying dimensions. I want to be able to scale all of these images with CSS to X% based on **their** dimensions, rather than the dimensions of their container.

Given this simple (and somewhat dumb) example:

```
<div style="width: 500px;">
    <img src="none.png" style="width: 50%;" />
    <!-- none.png dimensions: 200px by 1000px (L x W)-->

    <img src="none2.png" style="width: 50%;" />
    <!-- none2.png dimensions: 500px by 800px (L x W)-->
</div>
```

`none.png` will be set to a width of 250px where my goal is 500px and `none2.png` will be set to a width of 250px where my goal is 400px.

So... what am I missing here? How can I get CSS to resize based on the target rather than the container?

This can be done with JavaScript of course `$('img').css('width', $(this).width * 0.2)`... but can it be done in CSS natively?

Comment: That can be done only using JS

Comment: CSS `transform: scale(50%, 50%)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
img
   {
    min-width:50%;
    height:auto;
   }
```

Comment: This doesn't work either, but in a different way: http://jsfiddle.net/aLynLhs6/1/

Comment: apply width:auto; then check it